# Cannot display output view block under or after exposed filters block

Tags: views, blocks

I created few exposed filters in block. However when I hit 'apply', I get its output view displayed on top of the exposed filters in a separate block. Is their any way or code through which I can display the same output view under/after exposed filters, rather than on top of it.

I did change the sequence of 'Exposed form: view name' and 'View: view name' in block display region. i.e., I positioned the 'Exposed form: view name' on top of 'View: view name', yet still it didnt solve the problem. Any help or guideline will be greatly appreciated.